# MVC Razor Column headers extend beyond page on intranet published site

Tags: razor, intranet, asp.net-mvc-5.2, columnheader

I had a problem with MVC Razor Column headers extending beyond the web page area.

However, by wrapping my table in a div tag:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll">
```

the column headers (and data also) work just fine with a relevant horizontal scrollbar for my MVC 5.2.2 project using VS 2013 Premium Debugger.

However, when I "publish" it to an intranet site -- quite the experience in and of itself, don't forget to add it to your ie "intranet" zone in internet options, but I digress,
the problem re-occurs.  The header is extremely ugly with a "bar" extending off page, and the rightmost headers totally unreachable.

Although I changed this part of the MVC project many days ago, I changed some markup and verified that the new version *is* being "published" to the intranet site.

Does anyone have any insight into why an html tag would work in the debugger but not on a published intranet site?  Does it have to do with Internet Explorer 10 (10.0.9200.x) options or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit myself {I really did hope for an answer here}; I am hoping this will help someone else.

I should have posted more code:

I had the following

```
<div style="overflow:scroll">
    <h3>Index</h3>
    <table class="tableStyle">
         <tr style="position:relative;overflow:scroll">
```

turns out that the last line (for the row), the position attribute "interferes" with the scroll--
for whatever reason, this didn't show up in my VS2013 debug environment, but did on the intranet.

One needs to remove that (position:relative;"for it to work correctly.  The adjusted solution is:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll">
    <h3>Index</h3>
    <table class="tableStyle">
         <tr style="overflow:auto">
```

Thus it is the tr element that needs to be fixed.

If one truly needed the position:relative set, which I don't, not sure what one would do!

Finally, such things are sometimes helped by editing the .css file, making a class, and marking an attribute as important, but I did not do that in my case....